# Connect TFS over Citrix

Tags: tfs, citrix

I have to do synchronization task between multiple instance of TFS. However, the right-hand-side TFServer is inside Citrix.
Can I connect to TFSerer inside Citrix from outside Ctrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if the TFS server inside Citrix is exposed through some other way (public URL or TFS Web Access Server, VPN connection), I see no way to connect your Local Team Explorer to the TFS server inside Citrix